# On MacOS, is it better install Python with Homebrew or from python.org?

Tags: python, macos, pip, package

Because of all the SDK files and additional packages mixed up; I reset my MacBook. Now I want to install the SDKs and packages more carefully - the way that I can totally remove them from my system if I no longer need them.

You know Python SDK and some packages like pip etc. may stay as leftovers after removing Python. Also I don't know if the thing I read is true, which is there's already a default Python version on MacOS. I will use Python, pip, Jupyter Notebook, also Java JDK. I want a perfect order on my system.

Is it better installing Python with Homebrew or from python.org? And if I install it with python.org, am I able to install pip and Jupyter notebook easily? What is the best way to manage all SDKs and packages?

Comment: Have a look at [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) or [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/) there many other 'tool version managers'

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to install miniconda in order to install and manage multiple version of python.
Miniconda is just a lighter version of anaconda that only has a terminal interface.
You can install miniconda with homebrew (I always prefer to install anything with homebrew where that's possible so I can manage all my applications from there)